# What's the meaning of this inequality in the lot-sizing and scheduling problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming

I learned about the MILP models proposed by Pochet and Wolsey. Here are the formulations of one of these models(MILP3).

So the decision variables and the primary formulation are as following:
[image]

Based on these inequalities, the author added other variables and questions to optimize the model
[image]

He replaces the 6th inequality by four another inequalities.

Furthermore, the author optimize the model again.

[image]

I think I have learned the MILP1 and MILP2, but what's the meaning of the last inequality in MILP3. It is so obscure to me.

Answer (score 1):

The last inequality (11), the so-called "valid inequality" is more commonly known as a "cutting plane" or "cut". A cut is a redundant inequality (i.e., implied by the other constraints) which serves to cut off (i.e., render infeasible) some solutions from the continuous relaxation of the problem, i.e., make the continuous relaxation tighter relative to the integer-constrained problem. The only purpose is to (hopefully) solve the MILP faster than it would be solved without the cut(s). A cut may or may not have a "meaning"; its usefulness is judged by its effect on solution speed.